# How do I unmarshal this JSON

Tags: json, go

I have two func with the following signature:

```
 1)  func printAWSDataToConsole(edgexcontext *appcontext.Context, params ...interface{}) (bool, interface{}) {
```

and

```
  2)   func (f Conversion) TransformToAWS()
```

where

```
func NewConversion() Conversion {
    return Conversion{}
}
```

at first TransformToAWS was returning

```
      true, string(msg)
```

and I was able to print the value of msg in printAWSDataToConsole by doing a simple

```
     fmt.Println(params[0].(string))
```

Now I changed TransformToAWS to return a json:

```
    data := YuccaDataStream {
                 Stream : "temperatura2",
                 Sensor : "ec6c613a-66b4-4584-fb37-5f7cac130f7d",
                 Values : []Value {
                           Value {
                           Time:formattedTime,
                           Components: Components{Alfanum :"15.55"},
       }, }, }

     dataAsBytes, err := json.Marshal(data)

     return true, dataAsBytes
```

where

```
type YuccaDataStream struct {
    Stream string `json:"stream"`
    Sensor string `json:"sensor"`
    Values []Value `json:"values"`
    }

type Value struct {
    Time string `json:"time"`
    Components `json:"components"`
}

type Components struct {
    Alfanum string `json:"alfanum"`
}
```

I don't know how to unmarshal the json in printAWSDataToConsole.

Comment: `var x YuccaDataStream; json.Unmarshal(params[0].([]byte), &x)`

Comment: @Peter thank you, can you answer so I can vote it?

Comment: Why downvoting this question without a comment? It's clear and indeed a user has answered immediately.

Comment: "How do I decide JSON in Go" has been asked and answered countless times on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: for the audience, if you find this question useful, upvote it. cheers.

Comment: As shown in the answer, the problem was not just calling json.Unmarshal() but it was to retrieve the correct data from params[0].([]byte)   This could not be stated in the question, since it would have required a non-sense title. I provided all the details I thought were needed to understand the problem and re-read my question 3 times. I do not accept this downvote. just saying.

Answer (score 1):

To unmarshal use the following code:

```golang
var dataOut YuccaDataStream
err = json.Unmarshal(dataAsBytes, &dataOut)
```

That’s it. As simple as that.

Comment: The problem is that  in printAWSDataToConsole  I have (params ...interface{}) and i don't know how to retrieve dataAsBytes from params

Answer (score 0):

The problem was to understand how to get the data from params ... interface.
The answer is:

```
var dataStream YuccaDataStream;
json.Unmarshal(params[0].([]byte), &dataStream )
```

Comment: So the question (title) was wrong or misleading. Sorry for not directly responding to your question. Good to see you managed to solve it by yourself.